# Two column DIV layout becomes one column center aligned

Tags: css, layout, html, slice

In the center of my webpage I have a div with id center-container which contains 2 divs: one for a video player(on the left) and the second one (on the right) for an optional thing like playlist. Above and below the center-container div I have another content as well.

Now the question. How can I make my video player container to come to the middle of the page when the playlist div is absent (not set) without braking the remaining layout.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a pic of the elements?

Comment: Can you add your current HTML/CSS and optionally also create a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with less & simple code like this:

```
.playlist{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    background:blue;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.playlist + .video{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
}
.video{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:green;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/qcTSt/

Comment: WOW! :) Just explain why you put div class="playlist" which is floated to right before div class="video"?

Comment: because in my css code i said .playlist + .video which means if video after playlist then apply float:left & if there is no playlist then apply margin: 0 auto; in the video div.

Comment: This is a great solution to what I'm also looking for.  There's something that I'm not understanding though.  What's meant by "...video player container to come to the middle of the page when the playlist div is absent (not set)".  I don't understand what "(not set)" means.  if I delete the .playlist class then the playlist goes away, but that's only because there's no content in it.  If something exists in that DIV, it's still visible.  Is there a way of making your code work AND still having content in the playlist - in other words, have the playlist content invisible?

Answer (score 3):

got it!

http://jsfiddle.net/6y5N4/7/

have been using this eversince! just remove the content from the container that should be optional (like the playlist) and the other container should stretch without problem.

Comment: And what about not stretching but leaving the size of video player container constant and bringing it into middle?

Comment: @Karine: sort of. the browser should set the right floating div first so that the left div will be stretchable and adaptable to the right div.

Comment: @Karine: you could create a wrapper div with static dimensions inside the left div and center it using `margin:0 auto`. i'll update my code